# Jenkins workspace and git repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins, version-control

when Jenkins is setup with GitHub repository, on building the job manually , does Jenkins downloads everything from the repository into the local system or only the latest changed files that were committed on GitHub ? 
Also if I wish to pull specific file to my local workspace on Jenkins what SCM configurations I should specify ?

Answer (score 1):

When you queue a build for code from github by jenkins, jenkins will downloads the whole git repo from github, but it only build changes for the latest version/commit you specified.

If you want to build your local file by jenkins, you should commit the changes in local workspace (also it’s the local git repo for github), and then push it to github, then queue a build or use CI build  in Jenkins. detail steps to commit and push local change to github as below:

```
# In local git repo (parent folder is workspace)
# Assume your queue build for master in jenkins
git checkout master
# Add your local file in git repo
git add filename
git commit -m 'add local file'
git push
```

Then queue build in jenkins again, you will get the build result for your local file.

Comment: marina there must exist a workaround or setting by which I can prevent Jenkins from downloading the entire repository, because its a wastage of a lot of time and bandwidth. Thanks any inputs will be of great help!

Comment: No, jenkins will download all the commits of a git repo, this is because git is distribute VCS, it will always download the entire versions to local. And it won't take lots of time to download old versions.